# (Expo Ejected) Error Could not find the following native modules:

Tags: react-native, expo

After I ejected my project to bare react-native I receive this error when attempting to run iOS.
I have tried deleting the Pods folder and using pod install.

error Could not find the following native modules: RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, react-native-safe-area-context, RNScreens.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbwiI.png)

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.5